# Can't bind to 'items' since it isn't a known property of 'virtual-scroller'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, virtualscroll

I am having an issue with getting virtual scroll implemented into my ionic 4 + Angular project.

Previously, I have used ionic's implementation of virtual scroll (ion-virtual-scroll) which was working great initially but ran into a arguably big caveat of it not support ionic's grid view which is something that is required for my app. 
(Ionic have acknowledged this under their repo here under 'Feature requests': https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/16632)

In the meantime I have resorted to using ngx-virtual-scroller (https://github.com/rintoj/ngx-virtual-scroller) as it provides multi-column support

However, I am having trouble with using within my project.

I've installed it through npm (npm install ngx-virtual-scroller --save) and imported the VirtualScrollerMoudle within my app.module

**app.module.ts**

```
import { VirtualScrollerModule } from 'ngx-virtual-scroller'

imports: [
    ...
    VirtualScrollerModule
],
```

I've wrapped the virtual-scroller tag around my elements within the view of my component

**product-card-view.component.html**

```
<virtual-scroller #scroll [items]="productsArray">
  <div *ngIf="columnViewActive; else listView">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="6" *ngFor="let p of scroll.viewPortItems">
        <ion-card>
          <ion-card-header>
            <a class="productTitleColumn" title="{{ p.title }}" href="{{ p.link }}">{{ p.title }}</a>
          </ion-card-header>
          <ion-card-content>
            ..... ETC .....
          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </div>
</virtual-scroller>
```

But I am receiving this error

**Error in console**

> core.js:9110 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'items' since it isn't a known property of 'virtual-scroller'.
>   1. If 'virtual-scroller' is an Angular component and it has 'items' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'virtual-scroller' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
>   3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

After scouring for a solution I ran into someone else who faced a similar issue but with Ionic 3 (https://github.com/rintoj/ngx-virtual-scroller/issues/85) and their
solution was to import the VirtualScrollMoudle into the child module of where it was being used instead of the global app module and indicating it might have to be something to do
with using lazy-loading for components.

Unfortunately, I attempted that to no avail. I've tried importing the VirtualScrollMoudle to app.module.ts only, the parent page module of the component which is using 
virtual-scoller only and both at the same time but ran into the same issue.

**home.module.ts**

```
import { VirtualScrollerModule } from 'ngx-virtual-scroller'

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomePage
      }
    ]),
    FontAwesomeModule,
    ProductSharedModule,
    HeaderFooterSharedModule,
    HideHeaderSharedModule,
    VirtualScrollerModule
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule { }
```

I've also made sure that the import statements are at the bottom as I have seen that has managed to catch out quite a lot of people (Including myself in the past)

Is there any solutions or am I missing something quite obvious?

Versions:

Ionic 4 (5.4.4)

Angular: 8.1.3

Comment: Try restarting `ng serve` sometimes it doesn't pick up changes to files.

Comment: I gave that a shot but sadly had no luck, i've attempted a fresh build and npm install to ensure that it was installed also. There could be a small quirk between ionic 4 and this module

Comment: What module is `product-card-view` declared in?

Comment: It's declared within the home.module.ts page via a shared module but I have just noticed that the component is also featured on other pages as it's contained within a shared module used by other pages. I don't think that would be causing this error but I might try isolating the component to just one page to see the result

Comment: You should import the scroll module into the shared module that declares the component that uses it. Adding it to other modules won't make it usable.

Comment: You're right, I can tell its been a long day since I havent thought of doing that :D I'll give that a shot and I'll let you know if it works. Thanks for the quick replies!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE**

With many thanks to [@Reactgular](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1031569/reactgular) I have got the problem resolved!

As my **product-card-view.component** was inside a shared module, I needed to import the virtual scroll module within the shared module and **not** seperately within either app.module.ts or the parent page module

**product-shared.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { VirtualScrollerModule } from 'ngx-virtual-scroller';

// Product card component
import { ProductCardViewComponent } from '../../components/products/product-card-view/product-card-view.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ProductCardViewComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, IonicModule, FontAwesomeModule, VirtualScrollerModule],
  exports: [ProductCardViewComponent]
})
export class ProductSharedModule { }
```

I'll leave this answer up in hopes that it can help anyone in the future who faces a similar issue